# ¿Por qué mi input file no envía nada a través de Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Pude pasar una imagen y la información de otros datos de un formulario, pero estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo para editar la imagen, pero no me sale, me dice  Undefined index: imagen.

Código html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="editar_producto" name="editar_producto">
        <div id="resultados_ajax2"></div>

        <label for="foto" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Subir imagen</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" size="2048" accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg">            
        </div>
</form>
```

Esto lo tengo en productos.js

```
$( "#editar_producto" ).submit(function( event ) {
$('#actualizar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/editar_producto.php",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
         beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#resultados_ajax2").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
          },
        success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados_ajax2").html(datos);
        $('#actualizar_datos').attr("disabled", true);
        load(1);
      }
});
event.preventDefault();
})
```

Y esto en editar_producto.php (en donde está el update y hacia donde se envía la información).

```
 $type=$_FILES['imagen']['type'];
 $tmp_name = $_FILES['imagen']["tmp_name"];
 $name = $_FILES['imagen']["name"];

...
```

pero me dice Undefined index: imagen.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: prueba creando un `<input type=submit/>` y posiblemente sea eso, desconozco que exista el evento `submit` en JQ.

Comment: `data: new FormData(this),` this no es nada en ese contexto, es normal. Tienes que pasarle el formulario. mira aqui: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

En tu HTML cambai el id y el name a "file" :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="editar_producto" name="editar_producto">
        <div id="resultados_ajax2"></div>

        <label for="foto" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Subir imagen</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="2048" accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg">            
        </div>
</form>
```

**El jQuery:**

```
$( "#editar_producto" ).submit(function( event ) {
$('#actualizar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

            var imagen = $('#file')[0].files[0];        

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("file", imagen);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "ajax/editar_producto.php",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(objeto){
                    $("#resultados_ajax2").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
                    },
                    success: function(datos){
                    $("#resultados_ajax2").html(datos);
                    $('#actualizar_datos').attr("disabled", true);
                    load(1);
                    },
                    error: function (datos){
                    }
                });
```

TU PHP:

```
$type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
 $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']["tmp_name"];
 $name = $_FILES['file']["name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que te escribió Ivan no te llega a funcionar proba añadiéndole esto:

cambiar la línea

```
 data: formData,
```

por

```
 data: {varFormData: formData}
```

y en el código de "editar_producto.php" asegúrate que reciba la variable varFormData y que sea del tipo de dato "formData"

Saludos.